# In jira automation, can set a configure field of an issue to display its "is blocked by" issue?

Tags: jira, scrum, jql, jira-automation

In Jira I am trying to show in the swim lane card itself, on which issue it is blocked if blocked at all. For this I tried creating a configure field "Blocked by" and added it as a field to issue type Story.

Now I am trying to create automation that will trigger when a relation "blocks" or "is blocked by" is created. When such relation is created I want the field to get updated so that I can display it in Jira card.

For example: Issue B is blocked by Issue A, then In field "Blocked by" of issue A I want to display Issue B.

I already tried these steps:

1. From project settings went to Automation.
2. Selected "create rule"
3. In rule:
   Trigger: When Issue linked. Linked types = Blocks
   Action: Then edit issue fields. Chose "Blocked by" from drop down. In value I gave {{issue}}.
4. Save and Published.
5. While testing, Set Issue B "is blocked by" Issue A
   it is updating the Issue B's "Blocked by" field with "Issue A", which exactly opposite of what I want.
6. even if in the rule I change value to {{destinationIssue}}, then again its wrong as it puts value "Issue B" which is totally wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So finally its resolved. I got good directions from the Community leader of below Atlassian community. [Atlassian Community page](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/To-update-quot-Blocked-By-quot-through-automation-when-a-blocked/qaq-p/2402075?utm_campaign=solution_to_question&utm_medium=email&utm_source=atlcomm&utm_content=topic)

Answer lies in three steps.

1. first, is to trigger on issue type Linked (see picture)
   [image]
2. second, branch on rule / related issues and select Type of issue as  "Destination issue" (this realy makes sense if we want to update destination issue).
   [image]
3. Third, then selecting "Edit issue" action chose the field to set as, "Blocked by" (or any other you want). Then in value add this without quote "{{triggerIssue}} {{issue.Blocked by}}"
   [image]

Note: {{triggerIssue}} here is the one that gets updated for first time. If we create "blocked by" relation again it got appended by {{issue. Blocked by}}
Note2: Before all this I added "Blocked by" as one of the custom fields.

This field then I added on the card layout. Very good to have the Blocked by issue on the card of a particular issue on kanban board.